# Caveats when upgrading PHP 5.1.6 to 5.2.x?

Tags: php, centos

We have a years old server which is CentOS 5.2 and PHP 5.1.6. It serves mainly static html pages plus a few simply PHP webforms.

Now there is a need to upgrade PHP to 5.2.x for adding a new PHP onto the same server. Is there any caveat I should be aware of? Any experience to share with? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done so on a heavy server with millions of scripts, You'll notice almost nothing. The major change IMHO is :

```
$object.="x";
```

No longer works and errors, since objects are not automatically casted to strings via

```
__toString();
```

and you need to do that manually. But few scripts do that and those who do, usually cast manually.